# How can I show number of members on the subsite?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sub-site

I want to show the number of members on the SharePoint subsite page.

The image below, which is the top-level site, shows the number of members.
[image]

Then I create the subsite under the top-level site but no number of members shown.
[image]

How can I show the number of members of the subsite? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the behavior by default.

In fact, the members displayed in the site refer to the Microsoft Group. This is not available in the subsite, and currently there is no OOTB method to display it.

See this related blog: [Microsoft 365 Groups vs. SharePoint Permissions](https://www.syskit.com/blog/microsoft-365-groups-vs-sharepoint-permissions/)

[image]

Comment: +1 thanks so much